# Does SVN (subversion) have the mailbox commands similar to GIT format-patch and GIT am

Tags: svn

Does SVN (subversion) have the mailbox commands similar to

```
GIT format-patch
```

and

```
GIT am
```

Comment: I think closest commands are `svn diff` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) and `svn patch` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html)

Comment: Looks similar, but: 1 - diff doesn't contain info about commit  2 - I has the conflict in patch merging, because two repos has different list of revisions (patch from repo 1 linked to rev number from repo1, which doesn't exist in repo2)